# safari not showing circular div with shadow

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a div with the following css

```
close: {
        position: 'fixed',
        boxShadow: '1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
        borderRadius: '50%'
    }
```

It works well with Chrome, but not Safari.

Comment: Your css declaration is incorrect please add semicolon after your css properties.

Comment: you need to add 'webkit' in boxShadow.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. it might help solve your problem

```css
.close
{
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* for chrome and other browser*/
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  /*for safari */
        border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="close">

<h3>Check this out</h3>

</div>
```